# Delete rows from csv containing non-numeric content at a specific column

Tags: python, csv, conditional-statements

Here is my test data (in csv format):

```
"id","user_id","value"
"1","1001","111"
"2","1002","222"
"3","h82kn9;2&3","333"
"4","jsidofj882","444"
```

The goal is to eliminate all rows with a string as `user_id`. I would like to know how I can test whether the content of each line, corresponding to a certain column, is or is not a string. It could be *any* string.

I have made baby steps at writing the code, but I have to admit I have no idea how to proceed for the `if` part.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
for line in reader:
    if ##column 'user_id' is not a string##
        print line
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Python says `type("1000")` is `<type 'str'>`, do you mean a string with numbers vs letters?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant I want to keep only the `user_id`'s with all digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to test if a string contains only digits:

```
if line[1].isdigit():
    # all digits
```

Demo:

```
>>> "1001".isdigit()
True
>>> "jsidofj882".isdigit()
False
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the Pandas library [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/index.html). I would proceed as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read(your_file)
```

of from the string you provided:

import StringIO
   df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(your_csf_file_as_a_string))

df contains a dataframe with all you data:

```
   id     user_id  value
0   1        1001    111
1   2        1002    222
2   3  h82kn9;2&3    333
3   4  jsidofj882    444
```

Now is the filtering where we select the column of interest (user_id) and filter by selecting string that contains only digits:

```
filtered_df = df[df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]
```

filtered_df contains only the first 2 rows as expected:

```
   id user_id  value
0   1    1001    111
1   2    1002    222
```

Comment: This is very elegant as well, I didn't know about the pandas library. Thank you for your suggestion!